# In Linux, is there a way to align text on a delimiter?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, text-alignment

I have a script that basically runs `tmux ls`:

```
session1: 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:16:13 2013) [157x56]
stuff: 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:25:21 2013) [157x56]
asdf: 2 windows (created Sun Sep 29 23:06:33 2013) [77x17] (attached)
website: 1 windows (created Tue Sep 24 17:22:14 2013) [157x26]
```

I want the output of this script to be aligned at the colon, for readability.  I know to use `column -t` but it doesn't quite do what I want (note the double spacing, and that the colons aren't actually aligned):

```
session1:  3  windows  (created  Fri  Sep  20  13:16:13  2013)  [157x56]
stuff:     3  windows  (created  Fri  Sep  20  13:25:21  2013)  [157x56]
asdf:      2  windows  (created  Sun  Sep  29  23:06:33  2013)  [77x17]   (attached)
website:   1  windows  (created  Tue  Sep  24  17:22:14  2013)  [157x26]
```

Here's the output I really want:

```
session1 : 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:16:13 2013) [157x56]
stuff    : 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:25:21 2013) [157x56]
asdf     : 2 windows (created Sun Sep 29 23:06:33 2013) [77x17] (attached)
website  : 1 windows (created Tue Sep 24 17:22:14 2013) [157x26]
```

What's the easiest/best way to achieve this in the Linux shell?

---

**Edit**:  If you want to test your answer, you can use `curl -s nylen.tv/tmux.txt` instead of `tmux ls`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `GNU sed` you can specify the occurrence of the match so where `s/ +/ /g` would single space the whole file `s/ +/ /2g` single spaces the whole file but after the second match on each line:

```
$ column -t file | sed -re 's/: ( +)/\1: /' -e 's/ +/ /2g'
session1 : 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:16:13 2013) [157x56]
stuff    : 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:25:21 2013) [157x56]
asdf     : 2 windows (created Sun Sep 29 23:06:33 2013) [77x17] (attached)
website  : 1 windows (created Tue Sep 24 17:22:14 2013) [157x26]
```

To sort out the first columns spacing we use `s/: ( +)/\1: /` to match all the spaces from the `:` and we store n-1 spaces in the first capture group. We then replace the `:` and all the spaces with n-1 spaces followed by a `:` followed by a space *(making n total space again)*.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
cat tmux.txt | sed 's/:/ : /' | column -t -o' ' | sed 's/ \+/ /2g' 
session1 : 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:16:13 2013) [157x56]
stuff    : 3 windows (created Fri Sep 20 13:25:21 2013) [157x56]
asdf     : 2 windows (created Sun Sep 29 23:06:33 2013) [77x17] (attached)
website  : 1 windows (created Tue Sep 24 17:22:14 2013) [157x26]
```

Comment: I tried something similar.  The problem is that `\s\s` matches the spaces in between the names and the colons too, so the text is no longer aligned after the substitution.  Try it:  `curl -s nylen.tv/tmux.txt | sed 's/:/ : /' | column -t | sed 's/\s\s/ /g'`

Comment: Depending on your version of "column", there's an option '-o' that would let us specify an output separator. In your case, you would want to use a single space as the output separator.

Comment: I realized there were still 2 spaces before '(attached)'. Adding another substitution there.